# Is there a pattern to itertools.permutations

Tags: python, python-itertools

When i am iterating over an itertools.permutations, I would like to know at what indexes specific combinations of numbers would show up, without slowly iterating over the whole thing.

For example:

When I have a list, foo, which equals `list(itertools.permutations(range(10)))`, I would like to know at which indexes the first character will be a zero, and the seventeenth a three. A simple way to do this would be to check every combination and see whether it fits my requirement.

```py
n = 10
foo = list(itertools.permutations(range(n)))
solutions = []

for i, permutation in foo:
    if permutation[0] == 0 and permutation[16] == 3:
        solutions.append(i)
```

However, as n gets larger, this becomes incredibly slow, and very memory inefficient.

Is there some pattern that I could use so that instead of creating a long list I could simply say that if `(a*i+b)%c == 0` then I know that it will fit my pattern.

EDIT: in reality I will be having many conditions some of which also involve more than 2 positions, therefore I hope that by combining those conditions I can limit the amount of possibilities to the point where this becomes doable. Also, the 100 might have been a big bit, I am expecting n to not get larger than 20.

Comment: Have you read the *Roughly equivalent to:*  section of the [`itertools.permutations()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)? That's the algorithm used, in a nutshell.

Comment: Also, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? I strongly suspect that you *don't need to generate all permutations*.

Comment: If you have range(100) then you'll get 100! permutations. Using limitation for 2 cells reduces it to 98! permutations. Not a big save

Comment: I am getting a long list of linear equations, all of which are required to equal zero.I was thinking that if checked an equation that depended on only the third and eight variable, and found that a certain combination did not work, then I could from then on skip all permutations in which I knew that combination to exist. (I have been told that all the variables are different integers between 0 and n.

Comment: @mathfux 98! is 9900x smaller than 100!, and since I have multiple equations I could also limit far more than 2 cells. The 2 cells is just to keep the example in the question simpler

Comment: If there are only 8 parameters, then you might get away with this approach. But 8 is really starting to push limits and by the time you get to n=100, it will take longer than the lifetime of the sun to calculate

Comment: @DaanVanIJcken. Wait, are you trying to solve linear equations by finding all possible permutations of the answers?

Comment: @MadPhysicist now that you say it ...

Comment: I suggest you don't do that at all. Numpy and scipy have some nice matrix inversion tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that should get me a far more efficient solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a mapping between permutations of not fixed elements and corresponding permutations with fixed cells enrolled. For example, if you count permutations over list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and require a value 1, for zero cell and a value 2 for third cell, permutation `(0, 4, 3)` will be mapped to `(1, 0, 4, 2, 3)`. I know, tuples are not friendly for this case because they are immutable but lists has `insert` method which is pretty useful here. That's why I convert them to lists and then back to tuples.

```
import itertools

def item_padding(item, cells):
    #returns padding of item, e.g. (0, 4, 3) -> (1, 0, 4, 2, 3)
    listed_item = list(item)
    for idx in sorted(cells):
        listed_item.insert(idx, cells[idx])
    return tuple(listed_item)

array = range(5)
cells = {0:1, 3:2} #indexes and their fixed values
remaining_items = set(list(array)) - set(list(cells.values()))
print(list(map(lambda x: item_padding(x, cells), itertools.permutations(remaining_items))))
```

#### Output:

```
[(1, 0, 3, 2, 4), (1, 0, 4, 2, 3), (1, 3, 0, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2, 0), (1, 4, 0, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2, 0)]
```

To sum up, list conversions are quite slow as well as iterations. Despite that, I think this algorithm is a conceptually good example that reveals what can be done here. Use `numpy` instead if you really need to optimise it.

#### Update:

It works 6 seconds on my laptop if `array` is `range(12)` (with 3628800 permutations). It's three times more than returning not padded tuples.